# Form looses focus after single character input?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I created a form with a state attached to it , but after every character input the form looses focus.
i realize its because the state cause the form to re render how do i escape this?

````
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
  const [countries,setCountries] =useState([])
  const [ newName,setnewName ] = useState('')

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
    .then(response=>{
      setCountries(response.data)
    })
  },[])

  const handleChange = (event) =>{
    setnewName(event.target.value)
  }
  const Finder = ()=>{

    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <div>
            Find country : <input value={newName} onChange={handleChange} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <p>Meow</p>
    <Finder/>
    </div>
  )

}

export default App```
````

Answer (score 1):

As you are rendering `Finder` as a component and it  will be create a new function on each and every render instead as you are rendering it inside a component invoke it as a `function` like below

try changing  the return statement as

```
return(
  <div>
   <p>Meow</p>
   {Finder()}
  </div>
)
```

Please go through [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-jepsen-w9kxz?file=/src/App.js) sandbox for reference